# Find missing dereference with !obtrace

Tags: debugging, windbg

Anyone know of an easier way to find the missing dereference when using !obtrace?

Example output in Windbg is:

```
kd> !obtrace 0xfa96f700
Object: fa96f700        Image: cmd.exe
Sequence  (+/-)  Stack
--------  -----  ---------------------------------------------------
   2421d    +1  nt!ObCreateObject+180
                nt!NtCreateEvent+92
                nt!KiFastCallEntry+104
                nt!ZwCreateEvent+11
                win32k!UserThreadCallout+6f
                win32k!W32pThreadCallout+38
                nt!PsConvertToGuiThread+174
                nt!KiBBTUnexpectedRange+c

   2421e    -1  nt!ObfDereferenceObject+19
                nt!NtCreateEvent+d4
                nt!KiFastCallEntry+104
                nt!ZwCreateEvent+11
                win32k!UserThreadCallout+6f
                win32k!W32pThreadCallout+38
                nt!PsConvertToGuiThread+174
                nt!KiBBTUnexpectedRange+c

   2421f    +1  nt!ObReferenceObjectByHandle+1c3
                win32k!xxxCreateThreadInfo+37d
                win32k!UserThreadCallout+6f
                win32k!W32pThreadCallout+38
                nt!PsConvertToGuiThread+174
                nt!KiBBTUnexpectedRange+c

   24220    +1  nt!ObReferenceObjectByHandle+1c3
                win32k!ProtectHandle+22
                win32k!xxxCreateThreadInfo+3a0
                win32k!UserThreadCallout+6f
                win32k!W32pThreadCallout+38
                nt!PsConvertToGuiThread+174
                nt!KiBBTUnexpectedRange+c

   24221    -1  nt!ObfDereferenceObject+19
                win32k!xxxCreateThreadInfo+3a0
                win32k!UserThreadCallout+6f
                win32k!W32pThreadCallout+38
                nt!PsConvertToGuiThread+174
                nt!KiBBTUnexpectedRange+c

----  ----------------------------------------------------------
References: 3, Dereferences 2
```

If there are thousands of references it is pretty much impossible to find the missing dereference.